# passing value of form input to function onSubmit

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass the value of the form input (inside render property of the "nextNode" object) to a
handler function on submission. Any ideas?

```
    const nextNode = {
        id: `node-${schema.nodes.length + 1}`,
        content: `Node ${schema.nodes.length + 1}`,
        coordinates: [
          desiredcoordinates[0],
          desiredcoordinates[1],
        ],
        parent: null,
        level: 2,
        form: null,
        className:'button blue',
        render: ({id,form}) => (
          <div id={id} style={{ fontSize: '0.5rem', textAlign: 'left', padding: '4px', width: '70px', height: '40px' }} onClick={() => toggleSelect(id)}>
            <a>
              <form style={{ display: form? 'none' : 'block' }}>
                <label>Form: </label><input style={{ width: '25px', height: '12px' }} type='text'></input>
                <button type="submit" className='buttonInputSubmit'>+</button>
              </form>
              <div style={{ display: form? 'block' : 'none' }}> Form: {form}</div>
              <div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        )
        ,
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling on submission your input should be connected to a state and always be updating that state. Submission should not be used to set in values.

```
<const nextNode = {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("")

    function handleChange(e){
       setInput(e.target.value)
    }

    id: `node-${schema.nodes.length + 1}`,
    content: `Node ${schema.nodes.length + 1}`,
    coordinates: [
      desiredcoordinates[0],
      desiredcoordinates[1],
    ],
    parent: null,
    level: 2,
    form: null,
    className:'button blue',
    render: ({id,form}) => (
      <div id={id} style={{ fontSize: '0.5rem', textAlign: 'left', padding: '4px', width: '70px', height: '40px' }} onClick={() => toggleSelect(id)}>
        <a>
          <form style={{ display: form? 'none' : 'block' }}>
            <label>Form: </label><input style={{ width: '25px', height: '12px' }} type='text' value={input} onChange={handleChange}></input>
            <button type="submit" className='buttonInputSubmit'>+</button>
          </form>
          <div style={{ display: form? 'block' : 'none' }}> Form: {form}</div>
          <div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    )
    ,
  };
```

Comment: I tried it but e.target.value doesn't seem to work. My component is in the function format. ` const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("")

  const handleChange=(e)=>{
    console.log(e.target.value);

       setTextInput(e.target.value)
       console.log(`textInput: ${textInput}`)
  }
  const handleFormSub=(id)=>{
    const nodeToToggle = schema.nodes.find(node => node.id === id);
    nodeToToggle.form=textInput;

  }`